# Barplot with a basemap as a background

Tags: python, visualisation, matplotlib, cartopy

I have some data as a pandas DataFrame with values associated with longitude. I have plotted it as stacked bars like this:

[image: figure1]

A subset of the data as an example via df.to_dict():

```
{'Commodity driven deforestation': {'-80 to -70': 758.0,
  '-70 to -60': 6045.0,
  '-60 to -50': 10361.0,
  '-50 to -40': 5763.0,
  '-40 to -30': 59.0},
 'Forestry': {'-80 to -70': 336.0,
  '-70 to -60': 164.0,
  '-60 to -50': 2364.0,
  '-50 to -40': 4013.0,
  '-40 to -30': 243.0},
 'Shifting agriculture': {'-80 to -70': 8246.0,
  '-70 to -60': 5787.0,
  '-60 to -50': 5200.0,
  '-50 to -40': 7855.0,
  '-40 to -30': 1584.0},
 'Urbanization': {'-80 to -70': 35.0,
  '-70 to -60': 16.0,
  '-60 to -50': 19.0,
  '-50 to -40': 97.0,
  '-40 to -30': 18.0},
 'Wildfire': {'-80 to -70': 19.0,
  '-70 to -60': 53.0,
  '-60 to -50': 89.0,
  '-50 to -40': 65.0,
  '-40 to -30': 0.0}}
```

I would like to add a basemap in the background with outline of land and country borders.

This is my attempt so far:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf

crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=crs)

resol = '110m'  # use data at this scale
border = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', 
    name='admin_0_boundary_lines_land', scale=resol, facecolor='none', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.5)
land = cf.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', \
    scale=resol, edgecolor='k', facecolor=cf.COLORS['land'], alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.5)


ax.add_feature(land)
ax.add_feature(border)

test_x_pos = [-75, -65, -55, -45, -35] # Longitude where I want to bars to appear on the map

test_df['position'] = test_x_pos
test_df = test_df.set_index("position")
df_norm.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=colors_list, ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks(x_positions, labels)

ax.set_ylabel('Percentage')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.legend(title='labels', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

Which produces this:

[image]

The bars are placed just at positions [0,1,2,...] instead of the longitude values I pass it. But the ticks appear correctly at the corresponding longitudes.

Any advice what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the extent of your map and to normalize all data values (percenatges) to be within the map latitudes range:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# this function is based on the example from https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py
def plot_categories(ax, results, category_names, category_colors, y_min):
    """ Makes a chart with stacked bars representing results falling into specified categories. """
    labels = [float(k) for k in results.keys()]
    data = np.array(list(results.values()))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)

    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
        heights = data[:, i]
        starts = y_min + data_cum[:, i] - heights
        rects = ax.bar(labels, heights, bottom=starts, width=5, label=colname, color=color, zorder=6, alpha=0.8)

d = {'Commodity driven deforestation': {'-80 to -70': 758.0,
  '-70 to -60': 6045.0,
  '-60 to -50': 10361.0,
  '-50 to -40': 5763.0,
  '-40 to -30': 59.0},
 'Forestry': {'-80 to -70': 336.0,
  '-70 to -60': 164.0,
  '-60 to -50': 2364.0,
  '-50 to -40': 4013.0,
  '-40 to -30': 243.0},
 'Shifting agriculture': {'-80 to -70': 8246.0,
  '-70 to -60': 5787.0,
  '-60 to -50': 5200.0,
  '-50 to -40': 7855.0,
  '-40 to -30': 1584.0},
 'Urbanization': {'-80 to -70': 35.0,
  '-70 to -60': 16.0,
  '-60 to -50': 19.0,
  '-50 to -40': 97.0,
  '-40 to -30': 18.0},
 'Wildfire': {'-80 to -70': 19.0,
  '-70 to -60': 53.0,
  '-60 to -50': 89.0,
  '-50 to -40': 65.0,
  '-40 to -30': 0.0}}
  
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
# make a world map
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=crs)
resol = '110m'  # use data at this scale
border = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', 
    name='admin_0_boundary_lines_land', scale=resol, facecolor='none', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.5)
land = cf.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', \
    scale=resol, edgecolor='k', facecolor=cf.COLORS['land'], alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.5)

ax.add_feature(land)
ax.add_feature(border)
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90])
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, dms=True)
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()
y_range = y_max - y_min

test_x_pos = [-75, -65, -55, -45, -35] # Longitude where I want to bars to appear on the map
# longitudes will work as indexes
test_df['position'] = test_x_pos
test_df = test_df.set_index("position")

# make another axis with percentage on the right
secax_y2 = ax.secondary_yaxis(1.05)
secax_y2.set_yticks(np.arange(y_min, y_max + y_range/10, y_range/10))
secax_y2.set_yticklabels(np.arange(0, 100 + 10, 10))
secax_y2.set_ylabel('Percentage')
secax_y2.set_xlabel('Longitude', labelpad=20, loc='right')

# make normalized data, suitable to be plotted on the map
data = {}
for index, poi in test_df.iterrows():
    values = list(test_df.loc[index])
    sum_of_values = sum(values)
    # get each value of a category as a fraction of the sum of its all values scaled to the full latitudes range
    data[str(index)] = [(v / sum_of_values) * y_range for v in values]

# make category names and their colors
category_names = test_df.columns
colors = ['red', 'green', 'gold', 'magenta', 'black']
# show categories over the map
plot_categories(ax, data, category_names, colors, y_min)

ax.legend(title='labels', bbox_to_anchor=(1.08, 1), loc='upper left')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]